# Automorphisms of (nilpotent) groups : torsion cokernel on the abelianisation implies torsion cokernel on the center?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, automorphism-groups, nilpotent-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\End{End}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Z{Z}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}\DeclareMathOperator\Span{Span}\DeclareMathOperator\ker{ker}\DeclareMathOperator\coker{coker}\DeclareMathOperator\im{im}\newcommand{\Id}{\mathrm{Id}}$

### Notation

For a group $L$, denote its center by $\Z(L)$ and its abelianisation by $L_1 = L/L'$.

An automorphism $A \in \Aut(L)$
restricts to an automorphism $A_{\Z} \in \Aut(\Z(L))$ of the center and
quotients to an automorphism $A_1 \in \Aut(L_1)$ of the abelianisation.
We thus have $\mathbb{Z}$-linear maps $(A_1 - \Id) \in \End(L_1)$ and $(A_{\Z} - \Id) \in \End(\Z(L))$.

### Main questions

I am very interested in the following questions :

- **QA**: Suppose that $L_1 / \im(A_1 - \Id)$ is torsion, what can we say about $\Z(L) / \im(A_{\Z} - \Id)$ ?

  - **QA1**: For which groups $L$ can we conclude that $\Z(L)/\im(A_{\Z} - \Id)$ is torsion ?
  - **QA2**: Can we construct examples where $L_1/\im(A_1 - \Id)$ is any torsion abelian group
    and $\Z(L)/\im(A_{\Z} - \Id)$ is any abelian group ?
    Can we do so even with $L$ a finitely generated nilpotent group of class 2 ?

### Thoughts and related questions

Of course if $L$ is abelian the we have $Z(L)/\im(A_z-\Id)=L/im(A-Id)$ so we can realize all torsion abelian groups.

I tried constructing examples of QA2 where L is a nilpotent group of class 2.

The extension $1 \to L' \to L \to L_1 \to 1$ is central, namely $L' \subset \Z(L)$.

Define the skew-symmetric bilinear map $w : L_1 \times L_1 \to L'$
by $w(x_1, y_1) = [x,y]$ for any lifts $x,y \in L$ of $x_1, y_1 \in L_1$.
It satisfies $\ker(w^\flat) = \Z(L)/L'$ and $\im(w) = L'$.

We must have $A'(w(x_1,y_1)) = w(A_1(x_1),A_1(y_1))$ so $A_1$ uniquely determines $A'$ and thus $A$.

- **QB**: Is this enough to show that $L_1/\im(A_1 - \Id)$ is torsion $\implies$ $L'/\im(A'-\Id)$ is torsion ?
  (It would then follow that $\Z(L)/\im(A_{\Z}-\Id)$ is torsion.)

This also leads to ask :

- **QC**: Which $A_1 \in \GL(L_1)$ extend to $A \in \Aut(A)$, in other terms
  when does the formula $A'(w(a,b)) = w(A_1(a), A_1(b))$ yield a *well defined* element $A'\in \GL(L')$.

A necessary condition is that $w(a,b)=0 \implies w(A_1(a), A_1(b))=0$, namely that $A_1$ preserves $w$-orthogonality.

Understanding QC would yield conditions which may help answering QB.

### Examples and a solution to QA2

The Heisenber group is the central extension of $L_1 = \mathbb{Z}^2$ by $L' = \mathbb{Z}$ with generators $x,y$ for $L_1$ and $z = [x,y]$ for $L'$.

Now any $A_1 \in \Sp_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ will yield $A'(z)=z$, so $\coker(A'-\Id)=\mathbb{Z}$, and we may choose the $A_1$ so that $\coker(A_1-\Id)$ is torsion.

This example generalises with the center $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by $\mathbb{Z}/n$. Then by taking direct sums we may realize any abelian group, giving a partial positive answer to QA2. Is that right ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean $L_1/(A_1-\mathrm{Id})$. Do you mean $L_1/\mathrm{im}(A_1-\mathrm{Id})$? $L_1/\mathrm{ker}(A_1-\mathrm{Id})$?

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462822/automorphisms-of-nilpotent-groups-torsion-cokernel-on-the-abelianisation-imp#comment1201644_462822), since the title mentions the cokernel, it must be $L_1/{\operatorname{im}(A_1 - \mathrm{Id})}$ (but of course the question should be edited to make it precise).

Comment: @YCor Indeed, i meant $coker(A_1-Id)$ as LSpice mentionned. Thanks for suggesting / initiating the edition.

Comment: If my answer to QA2 is correct, then I think you may close the post. 
Indeed it also provides a satisfactory answer to QA1: even under very strong condition "nilpotent of class 2" we can realize every abelian group as $coker(A_z-Id)$. 
The questions B and C, although interesting in their own right arose as an attempt to understand the restrictions on extension properties of (outer) automorphisms for general nilpotent groups in the hope to find restrictions, but as the examples shows they will not change the positive answer to QA2.